# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets based on the cell above (for multiple cells)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPDiy.png)I want to make a conditional formatting formula to ensure our invoices are in order and none are skipped using the invoice number in column B. So basically I want a formula that applies to all the cells. For example, B3=B2+1, but I want to be able to create a formula so that we do not have to manually add this formatting to every single line item.

B3=B2+1 Dragged this down but it did not apply to all cells

Answer (score 1):

Key is a range you apply formula to. Try:

`=and(B3<>B2+1,B3<>"")` on range `B3:B1000`

Result:

[image]